# Fuzzy matching gives unmatched data

Tags: r, matching, fuzzy

Hi I want to merge df1 and df2 based on x.

```
df1<-tibble(x=c("TRP OVERSEAS STOCK |","PIMCO TOTAL RETURN FUND"),y=c(1,2))

df2<-tibble(x=c("AB Portfolios: AB Growth Fund; Class K Shares","PIMCO TOTAL RETURN FUND"),z=c(2020,2021))
```

However, when I use

`fuzzy_join(df1, df2, match_fun = function(x,y) str_detect(y, x), by = "x")`

It gives me the following output,

[image]

`"TRP OVERSEAS STOCK |"` should not be matched with anything. But they are listed in the output. I'm wondering why does that happen and how to solve this issue? Thank you!!

Comment: Could you please elaborate which package you use for `fuzzy_join`?

Comment: Hi! I am using `install.packages("fuzzyjoin")`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `|`, as it is being used as an "or". So, it is just joining to the other rows. However, we could remove it first, then still use `fuzzyjoin`.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(x = str_replace_all(x, "[|]", "")) %>% 
  fuzzy_join(., df2, match_fun = function(x,y) str_detect(y, x), by = "x")
```

Or if you don't want to load more packages, then we could make the change in base R first.

```
df1$x <- gsub("[|]", "", df1$x)

fuzzy_join(df1, df2, match_fun = function(x,y) str_detect(y, x), by = "x")
```

**Output**

```
  x.x                         y x.y                         z
  <chr>                   <dbl> <chr>                   <dbl>
1 PIMCO TOTAL RETURN FUND     2 PIMCO TOTAL RETURN FUND  2021
```

Comment: Interesting. Thank you Andrew! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide whether to fuzzyjoin or not. If fuzzyjoin follow the answer by @AndrewGB and also [Fuzzy matching two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72009046/fuzzy-matching-two-data-frames/72009191?noredirect=1#comment127264820_72009191) your last question.

And if not fuzzyjoin then:

```
df2 %>% inner_join(df1, by = "x")
```

```
  x                           z     y
  <chr>                   <dbl> <dbl>
1 PIMCO TOTAL RETURN FUND  2021     2
```